# RTD Server : how to read RTD server data in C#

Tags: rtd, real-time-updates, real-time-data

I have developed an application to read data from excel spreadsheet which get data from RTD server. So whenever spreadsheet get updated I can write that data to database using C#.
But my concern is that I don't want to rely on that spreadsheet as an intermediate source of data from RTD server. Is it possible to get data directly from that RTD server in my application so why I can store that in database.
That must be possible, and i just need hint to do this.

Thanks. DnyaN :)

Comment: What protocol does that server support?

Comment: may be it is using COM protocol

Comment: @alexm i solved this issue... :)

Comment: @dnyan86 I'm trying to do the exact same thing, can you help?

Comment: The least you can do is share the solution you found @alexm.